# Como pegar valor do linha do banco e colocar no checkbox

Tags: php

Bom dia, estou com um problema aqui, criei uma linha `<p>` que me mostra os dados da tabela do banco de dados **id** e o **hora**. O que eu precisava é pegar esse valor e colocar no `value` do checkbox para que possa enviar essas informações em outra tabela da forma que colocasse o checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Hdisponivel[]" value="e colocava o valor da tabela aqui para poder selecionar que no caso seria o hora_de_segunda" />
```

meu código:

```
<?php include("../php/agenda.php"); include("../php/alterar.php"); ?>


    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="pt-br" ng-app="AngularADM">

    <body ng-controller="TempoHorasP1">



        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <h2 class="dourado texto-centro margin-top30 bold">Configuração da agenda online</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="row">

                <h3 class="texto-centro dourado">Agenda da 1º semana</h3>
                <hr />

                <div class="center-block">
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-lg-3 texto-centro bloco-hora">
                            <p class="margin-top10">Segunda feira</p>
                            <hr />



                            <?php

    if($total > 0) {

        do {

?>


                                <div class="col-lg-4 texto-centro hora-banco">

                                    <p>
                                        <?=$linha['id']?>
                                    </p>

                                </div>

                                <div class="col-lg-4 texto-centro hora-banco">
                                    <p>
                                        <?=$linha['horas_de_segunda']?>
                                         <input type="checkbox" name="Hdisponivel[]" value="" />
                                    </p>

                                </div>


                                <?php

        }while($linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dados));

    }
?>

                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-3 texto-centro bloco-hora">
                            <p class="margin-top10">Terça feira</p>
                            <hr/>




                            <?php

    if($terc > 0) {

        do {

?>
                                <div class="col-lg-4 texto-centro hora-banco">
                                    <p>
                                        <?=$terLinha['id']?>
                                    </p>

                                </div>

                                <div class="col-lg-4 texto-centro hora-banco">
                                    <p>
                                        <?=$terLinha['horas_de_terca']?>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="Hdisponivel[]" value="" />

                                    </p>

                                </div>


                                <?php

        }while($terLinha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ter));

    }
?>

                            <input type="submit" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-3 texto-centro bloco-hora">
                            <p class="margin-top10">Quarta feira</p>
                            <hr/>




                            <?php

    if($qua > 0) {

        do {

?>

                                <div class="col-lg-4 texto-centro hora-banco">
                                    <p>
                                        <?=$quarLinha['id']?>
                                    </p>

                                </div>

                                <div class="col-lg-4 texto-centro hora-banco">
                                    <p>
                                        <?=$quarLinha['horas_de_quarta']?>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="Hdisponivel[]" value="" />
                                    </p>

                                </div>



    </body>


    </html>
```

agenda.php:

```
<?php
//require_once 'valida.php';
// definições de host, database, usuário e senha
include("conexao.php");

mysqli_select_db($link, $bd);

// cria a instrução SQL que vai selecionar os dados
$selecionar = "SELECT id, horas_de_segunda FROM horas_segunda";

// executa a query
$dados = mysqli_query($link, $selecionar) or die(mysqli_error($link));

// transforma os dados em um array
$linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dados);

// calcula quantos dados retornaram
$total = mysqli_num_rows($dados);


//segundo
$terca = "SELECT id, horas_de_terca FROM horas_terca";

$ter = mysqli_query($link, $terca) or die(mysqli_error($link));

$terLinha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ter);

$terc = mysqli_num_rows($ter);


//terceiro

$quarta = "SELECT id, horas_de_quarta FROM horas_quarta";

$quar = mysqli_query($link, $quarta) or die (mysqli_error($link));

$quarLinha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($quar);

$qua = mysqli_num_rows($quar);

?>
```

Como eu poderia fazer, resumindo tudo isso preciso pegar o valor do `mysqli_num_rows($quar);` e colocar no `<input type="checkbox" name="Hdisponivel[]" value="aqui dentro" />`

Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta que você dê um `echo` da variável, dentro do campo `value=""` do `input` que você quer.

**Exemplo**

```
<?php   $animal = 'gato';   ?>

<input type="text" value="<?= $animal ?>" />
```

**A variável dentro do "`<?= ?>`" é o mesmo que "`<?php echo $animal; ?>`"**

Tente isso: `$hora_on = (isset( $_POST['Hdisponivel[]'] )) ? $_POST['Hdisponivel[]'] : '';`

Comment: fiz dessa forma so que o meu insert nao esta funcionando aparece esse erro **Notice: Undefined index: Hdisponivel in C:\wamp64\www\site\php\HorasDisponivel.php on line 11** e a minha linha 11 é este `$hora_on = $_POST['Hdisponivel[]'];` poderia me ajudar?

Comment: fiz de acordo com o que você explicou

Comment: Editei a resposta. Tente isso aí.

Comment: erro sumiu, so que não aparece os dados no banco de dados

Comment: Ah, cara, parece que você está meio perdido aí. Você fez o seu código ou copiou de algum lugar?

Comment: Eu que fiz, o que eu fiz coloquei um form, depois criei um insert com o checkbox e pegando os valores que sao puxados no banco e depois tentei enviar com o submit, so que o valores não estão indo, eu vou abrir outra pergunta pra não ficar confuso, mas cara obrigadão mesmo ajudou aqui pois o problema agora é outro.

Comment: Entendi. Boa sorte aí.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Hdisponivel[]" value="<?php echo myVar;?>" />
```

Ao defenir o name com "[]" voce está passando para o Post uma variável do tipo array. Isto significa que você tem que fazer um loop (normalmente um foreach) para conseguir obter o valor. Caso você pretenda aceder "diretamente" ao valor do Post sem o loop escreve assim:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Hdisponivel" value="<?php echo myVar;?>" />
```